# CodeIgniter and Facebook Connect

Tags: facebook, codeigniter, sdk

I am trying to integrate my Codeigniter website with the Facebook PHP SDK.  What I want to do is let a user share an article from my site on their facebook wall, if they are logged into a facebook account.  My library appears to load correctly, but everytime I try to do something, I get some kind of error... primarily with the auth.  getUser does not appear to return the correct results.  I set up my facebook application and set the config vars for my library, but no luck.  It says I am not logged into facebook.  When I click on the "login" anchor, the link takes me to the same page, but with the facebook url, and doesn't ask me to login with the app.  Here's my code:

function facebook($article_id){

```
$config = array(
    'appId' => '276870792431073',
    'secret' => '8d49eee575413fb9a8063d22f65dbf6a'
);

$this->load->library('facebook', $config);

$user = $this->facebook->getUser();

if($user){

    try {

        $user_profile = $this->facebook->api('/me');

    } catch (FacebookApiException $e){

        error_log($e);
        $user = null;

    }

}

if($user){

    $article = $this->article->fetch_article($article_id);
    $config = array(
        'message' => 'I just read an '.anchor('articles/'.url_title($article['title']).'/'.$article_id, 'article').' on '.anchor('', 'TrackTheOutbreak.com').'!',

    );

    $this->facebook->api('/me/feed', 'post', $config);

} else {

    $data['MESSAGE_TITLE'] = 'Authentication Error';
    $data['MESSAGE_TEXT'] = 'You must be logged into an existing Facebook account to use this feature.  Click '.anchor($this->facebook->getLoginUrl(), 'here').' to login.';
    $this->parser->parse('error_body.tpl', $data);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In order to access a users information and post anything to their wall you first need to get a access token from them. To do that you need to make sure that you have gained their permission through Facebook's FB_login (and then Open Graph). I would double check with this guide and make sure that you have everything set up properly to post to their timeline.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/

I hope this helps